# Exporting .obj-model to three.js json-object causes python-errors

Tags: python, shell, three.js, converters

I trie to export a 3D-model to use is in my three.js script. Unfortunately I am not familiar with python and all 3D stuff so much.

When I run the converter-script (convert_obj_three.py) from the windows shell I get an error. (The script and the model are in the same directory.)

```
$ c:/Python33/python convert_obj_three.py -i couch.obj -o couch.js
File "convert_obj_three.py", line 781
print "WARNING: skipping morph [%s] with different number of vertices [%d] than the original model [%d]" % (name, n_morph_vertices, n_vertices)

                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this because there is a problem with the model or do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you use Python 3 instead of Python 2 to run the script.

Python 2:

```
print ''
```

Python 3: print is a function and no keyword so it needs brackets:

```
print('')
```